# Android Hilt pass "assisted" parameters to ViewModel constructor

Tags: android, mvvm, android-viewmodel, dagger-hilt

As for 2023, is there any better or less boilerplate way to Inject assisted parameters into ViewModel aside from [this way](https://github.com/google/dagger/issues/2287)?

```
    class PlantDetailViewModel @AssistedInject constructor(
    plantRepository: PlantRepository,
    @Assisted private val savedStateHandle: SavedStateHandle,
    @Assisted private val plantId: String
) : ViewModel() {

    @AssistedFactory
    interface PlantDetailViewModelFactory {
        fun create(handle: SavedStateHandle, plantId: String): PlantDetailViewModel
    }

    companion object {
        fun provideFactory(
            assistedFactory: PlantDetailViewModelFactory,
            owner: SavedStateRegistryOwner,
            defaultArgs: Bundle? = null,
            plantId: String
        ): AbstractSavedStateViewModelFactory = object : AbstractSavedStateViewModelFactory(owner, defaultArgs) {
            @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
            override fun <T : ViewModel?> create(key: String, modelClass: Class<T>, handle: SavedStateHandle): T {
                return assistedFactory.create(handle, plantId) as T
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And consume it in the Fragment as

```
    @AndroidEntryPoint
class PlantDetailFragment : Fragment() {

    private val args: PlantDetailFragmentArgs by navArgs()

    @Inject
    lateinit var plantDetailViewModelFactory: PlantDetailViewModelFactory

    private val plantDetailViewModel: PlantDetailViewModel by viewModels {
        PlantDetailViewModel.provideFactory(plantDetailViewModelFactory, this, arguments, args.plantId)
    }
}
```

Comment: you can skip "provideFactory" part and use @,HiltViewModel  and @,Inject constructor(
    private val currentUser: CurrentUser,
    private val amazonS3DataSource: AmazonS3DataSource,
    val projectWorkSpaceRepo: ProjectWorkSpaceRepository
)

Comment: Can you provide a more detailed example please?

Answer (score 0):

The issue you mentioned was finally resolved and starting from [Dagger 2.49](https://github.com/google/dagger/releases/tag/dagger-2.49), assisted injection is properly supported in Hilt: https://dagger.dev/hilt/view-model#assisted-injection

This is how your ViewModel should look like:

```kotlin
@HiltViewModel(assistedFactory = MyViewModel.Factory::class)
class MyViewModel @AssistedInject constructor(
  @Assisted val assistedArg: String,
  private val savedStateHandle: SavedStateHandle,
  private val someDependency: SomeDependency,
) : ViewModel() {
  @AssistedFactory interface Factory {
    fun create(assistedArg: String): MyViewModel
  }
  ...
}
```

And this is how you can create it:

```kotlin
private val myViewModel by viewModels<MyViewModel>(
  extrasProducer = {
    defaultViewModelCreationExtras.withCreationCallback<MyViewModel.Factory> { factory -> 
      factory.create(assistedArg = "abc")  
    }
  }
)

// or in Compose
val viewModel = hiltViewModel<MyViewModel, MyViewModel.Factory>(
  creationCallback = { factory -> factory.create(assistedArg = "abc") }
)
```

I have `SavedStateHandle` as a dependency there just as a reminder it can be added as a regular dependency since it's a binding from `ViewModelComponent`.

Comment: hi @Fred Porciúncula, i have a similar problem to this question, but not hilt, can you take a look? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78089473/assistedinject-in-viewmodel-using-dagger-not-hilt-just-dagger-does-not-compi, i am not sure where to look at at this point, in all examples i have seen , nobody mentions the error i am receiving.